Properties of a diverging integral
Assume that $\epsilon:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous bounded function such that $\lim_{s \to \infty}\epsilon(s)=0$. Assume also that
$$
\int_{t_0}^t \frac{\epsilon(s)}{s} ds \to-\infty, \quad t \to \infty, 
$$
where $t_0>0$ is just a finite constant.
QUESTION: Is it true that, necessarily, for any sequences $t_n\to \infty, c_n\to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\exp \left(\int_{t_n}^{c_n t_n} \frac{\epsilon(s)}{s} ds \right)=O(1)
$$
or such a property does not need to hold?
Of course the simplest way to go would be to prove that necessarily there is $s_0$ so that $\epsilon(s) < 0$ for all $s\geq s_0$, but I'm not sure this needs to hold.
